# recoger campo select de un formulario para usarlo en la misma pagina sin enviar

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Me explico, tengo una base de datos con diferentes tablas entre ellas la que estoy usando en este caso es la tabla familia, que tiene estas columnas:

```
 id, familia_productos, importe_alquiler, tiempo_alquiler
```

Por otra parte tengo un panel que sirve para crear tickets de pedidos.

Resulta que tengo un select que se encarga de recorrer en la base de datos las familias que son unas 10 a lo mucho, hasta aquí bien.

> ticket.php

```
            <div class="radius-lg bg-default">
                <div class="jumbotron bg-white border-0 border-gray2 radius">
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <label>Seleciona una familia de productos:*</label>
                    <select id="nombre_familia" form="contact_form" required="" class="classic_form big radius-lg bg-white bs-light-focus">
                        <?PHP
                        $administrador = Familia::recuperarTodos();
                        foreach ($administrador as $ad) :
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?PHP echo $ad['id']; ?>"><?PHP echo $ad['familia_productos']; ?></option>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Que necesito?**

> Recoger de alguna forma la opción seleccionada para después poder
> trabajar con ella en la misma pagina sin enviar nada ya que este
> select es solo funcional y no se envía a ninguna base de datos,
> también me gustaría **saber despues como trabajar con ella para comparar
> este select guardado que hemos elegido con otro campo de otra tabla
> distinta(ambas tablas estan unidas por clave foranea) de esta base de
> datos.**

==============================================================
**Mis avances:**

Mientras espero una respuesta he estado investigando por mi cuenta también pero aún no me sale correctamente.

- lo que he hecho:

> funcionesTicket.js

```
(function() {
        "use strict"
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 

var nombre_familia = document.getElementById('nombre_familia');

 

}); // DOM CONTENT LOADED 

})();
        nombre_familia.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var selectedValue = nombre_familia.value;
  console.log(selectedValue);

  // Realizar una solicitud AJAX al servidor

  // Crear objeto XMLHttpRequest
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Configurar la solicitud
  xhr.open("POST", "/ticket.php", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  // Configurar la función de respuesta
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Se recibió la respuesta del servidor
      var respuestaPHP = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(respuestaPHP);
    }
  };

  // Enviar los datos al servidor
  xhr.send("selectedValue=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedValue));
});
```

> ticket.php

```
<?php
    // Obtener el valor enviado desde JavaScript
        $selectedValue = $_POST['selectedValue'];

        echo "el valor es:" . $selectedValue;
?>
```

Hasta aquí he llegado, pero como no envió los datos del select creo que nunca recibo el $_POST/$_GET (he probado ambos), como puedo recoger estas variables correctamente? Necesito comparar ambas variables en el mismo fichero sin envíos ya que se selecciona el select y debería mostrar a continuación los productos filtrados.

==============================================================

**Que veo en mi web:**

Cuando invoco el post en ticket.js si pongo por ejemplo

```
echo "el valor es: ".$_POST['selectedValue'];
```

aparece vacio y se lee

> el valor es:

en cambio en la consola aparece así:

> el valor es: 3

==============================================================

**Resumen de funcionamiento para entender mejor porque necesito guardar el campo select:**

> Estamos en el panel 1, al seleccionar la familia deseada del select,
> pulsamos para rellenar los datos del panel 2, la idea es que en el
> panel 2 con la familia elegida filtre los productos que aparecen aquí
> para que se vean los que pertenecen a dicha familia, continuamos al
> panel 3 elegimos otros datos, continuamos al panel 4 rellenamos mas
> datos y enviamos a traves de un documento externo javascript por ajax
> los datos del formulario sin el select, que solo era visual para poder
> hacer mas facil el funcionamiento.

Comment: Si los datos son unos pocos cientos puedes guardarlos en variables javascript y realizar el filtrado en el cliente. Si son muchos datos puedes usar AJAX que sería la mejor opción o cada vez que cambias el `select` realizar un submit. De todas maneras tu pregunta es muy amplia, no es un problema puntual si no mas bien es "hacerte el trabajo" por lo que votaré para cerrarla.

Comment: los datos del select a lo mucho son 10 datos creo yo, pero si engloba mas productos. disculpa como podría usar ajax en este caso? me pilla verde el tema ajax.

Comment: 1) Si tu pones `method: 'GET'` en PHP pones  `$_GET[nombrevariable]`.- 2) si pones `data: { familia_id: selectedValue },` quiere dices que envías información en una variable que se llama `selectedValue`, entonces en PHP pones  `$_GET['selectedValue']`

Comment: disculpa es cierto, fue un error de escritura, como llevaba rato trasteando escribi mal la pregunta, estoy colocando get en ajax y get en el codigo php y viceversa, post en ajax y post en php.   A pesar de que en mi codigo si lo hayapuesto bien jamas recibo la variable post o get en mi codigo? pero tambien es cierto que no pulso ningun boton de enviar porque en ese paso aun no se requiere, puede ser este el error? se debe de enviar si o si?

Comment: No es necesario un botón, si `nombre_familia` es el select, tu estas agregando el evento `change` y ese evento hace la solicitud. En este evento tu tienes `console.log(selectedValue); ` si esto se imprime en consola cada vez que cambias el select es que está todo bien hasta ahí

Comment: si hasta aqui funciona correctamente, pero no recibo el dato del post/get en mi web al llamarlo, una cosa que me ha llamado la atención es que el response enseña en la consola la pagina de ticket que es a la que va enviada si miro el codigo ahi si veo el valor del post pero no en la web y no entiendo muy bien porque.

Comment: No ves un error de CORS, no?

Comment: @gbianchi no, no aparece  esto es que veo en consola 2
funcionesticket.js:47 1
funcionesticket.js:47 3
ticket.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
funcionesticket.js:47 4  cuando voy cambiando el select

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta ha mutado mucho, pero para no seguir iterando en el tema aqui tienes un ejemplo

```
<select onchange="solicitar(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
    <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
</select>
<script>

    function solicitar(selectedValue) {
        console.log("Entra al evento onchagen!");
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ticket.php',
        method: 'GET',
         dataType: "json", //retornemos un json
        data: { familia_id: selectedValue },
        success: function(response) {
            
        console.log(response); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Manejar errores de la solicitud AJAX
        console.error(error);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Y en ticket.php

```
  $familia_id = $_GET["familia_id"];

  //Aqui tu llamarias a una función que te retornaria una lista. En aquella función le pasarias como parametro $familia_id
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = $familia_id;
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = $familia_id;
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = $familia_id;
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = $familia_id;
  echo json_encode($lista_de_Ejempo);
?>
```

Con esto compruebas la comunicación, ahora bien según entiendo tu segundo paso sería crear otro "select", seria algo así:

```
<select onchange="solicitar(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
    <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
</select>

    <select id="otroSelect">

    </select>
<script>

    function solicitar(selectedValue) {
        console.log("Entra al evento onchagen!");
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ticket.php',
            method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { familia_id: selectedValue },
        success: function(response) {
            crearSelect(response);

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Manejar errores de la solicitud AJAX
        console.error(error);
        }
    });
    }
    function crearSelect(lista) {
        let otroSelect = document.getElementById("otroSelect");
        otroSelect.innerHTML = ""; //limpiamos
        for (let item of lista) {
            otroSelect.appendChild(crearOption(item.id,item.Nombre))
        }
    }
    function crearOption(id, text) {
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = id;
        opt.text = text;
        return opt;
    }
</script>
```

```
<?php

  $familia_id = $_GET["familia_id"];

  //Aqui tu llamarias a una función que te retornaria una lista. En aquella función le pasarias como parametro $familia_id
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = (object)["id" => 1, "Nombre" => "Nombre 1" ];
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = (object)["id" => 2, "Nombre" => "Nombre 2" ];
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = (object)["id" => 3, "Nombre" => "Nombre 3" ];
  $lista_de_Ejempo[] = (object)["id" => 4, "Nombre" => "Nombre 4" ];
  echo json_encode($lista_de_Ejempo);
?>
```

Y si te fijas en el javascript, en esta línea

```
otroSelect.appendChild(crearOption(item.id,item.Nombre))
```

Tenemos `item.id` y `item.Nombre`, esto sale del PHP
`$lista_de_Ejempo[] = (object)["id" => 1, "Nombre" => "Nombre 1" ];` donde creamos un objetos que tiene como propiedades `id` y `nombre`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en responderme! agradezco muchísimo tu ayuda de verdad! si bien es cierto esto no es lo que estoy buscando exactamente.  lo que yo busco es poder recibir la variable js del select guardada a mi archivo php, en teoria se recibeun solo numero que hace referencia a un id y este id lo comparo con la clave foranea de otra tabla para ver si coinciden de este modo enseño unos productos u otros. He probado tu codigo para ver si conseguia hacerlo funcionar pero no ha sido el caso me sigue pasando igual, en la web no se lee el valor del metodo post/get

Comment: por lo tanto nunca compara el post con el id del que ya disponia de la otra tabla. La pregunta no ha mutado, sigue siendo la misma, solo la he mejorado y he añadido mis progresos para que resulte mas facil una posible respuesta creo yo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tu pregunta no se puede responder, ni yo ni nadie te va a entregar la respuesta entera, es mucho lo que estas pidiendo y es básicamente que te hagan el trabajo y eso es lo que te trataba de explicar en mi 1er comentario. Luego tu te centraste en un problema en particular "no te llega la Id" y por ahí ya se puede responder algo. Esto no es un foro ni un sistema de soporte, entonces que nos vayas contando como avanzas para solucionar el Todo no tiene cabida, porque luego de todo el trabajo van a cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Igualmente quise responderte algo, para que tuvieras una base desde donde empezar (arriesgándome a que me votaran negativo). El ejemplo que te puse funciona y está probado, en el primer caso puedes ver como si llega la Id al servidor, ya que este la devuelve y se muestra por consola Si a ti no te funciona el problema está en otro lado

Comment: En fin esto me supera, me han metido en un marrón que debo arreglar yo sola y no entiendo ni que estoy haciendo, para colmo intento mejorar mi pregunta de buena fe siempre, porque era mucho trabajo, lo comprendo, que es hacerme "todo el trabajo" tambien puedo entenderlo, no era la intencion solo era ver un poco de luz,

Comment: sigo mejorando la pregunta con lo que he encontrado para que al final la respuesta sea mas facil y poder demostrar que realmente me lo estoy currando yo tambien buscando respuestas y probando y que no sea "todo el trabajo" y de todas formas sigue siendo mal y cuidado que te voten negativo, no problem intentare apañarmelas yo. GRACIAS.

Comment: @MyNameIsUnknown cuando tienes que hacer muchas cosas y no sabes hacerla, centrate en un problema por ves.. un problema.. tu primer problema, es como pedirle a php que te devuelva algo.. no importa que.. primero eso... luego ver que te devuelva algo, dependiendo lo que vos mandes... eso son los pasos.. no vas a poder agarrar un sistema y meter todo ahi, si realemente no sabes como.. vas a tener que hacerlo por separado, hasta que entiendas como...

Comment: Ojo no te estoy queriendo decir que no te estes esforzando, el tema es que el sitio tiene un formato, la respuesta al 100% de tu pregunta involucra javascript, ajax, php, la base de datos, funciones propias que tienes para las consultas que ni sabemos que retornan y cuantas hay, entonces no se puede responder porque es mucho. Por eso debes partir el problema como te indica gbianchi, el primer paso es recibir la Id, yo te he puesto un ejemplo que funciona 100% seguro

Comment: He leído tu actualización y creo que no entiendes como funcionas ajax. En una situación normal (sin ajax) el navegador envía una solicitud al servidor PHP, el PHP genera un documento HTML y se lo devuelve al navegador, este lo renderiza y te lo muestra, todo este proceso genera una recarga en la página. Con ajax no se recarga la página, por lo que el navegador no renderiza la respuesta automaticamente. Una llamada ajax es una llamada que se hace por atrás, el servidor te da una respuesta en algún formato (HTML, XML, JSON, Texto) y es tu deber modificar la página (el DOM) usando Javascript

Comment: Mi segundo ejemplo, la función `crearSelect` hace justamente eso, recibe la respuesta del servidor y la procesa generando nuevos `<option>` para el segundo select,